# dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Address already in use

Tags: sockets, networking, tftp, dnsmasq

when i try to start the dnsmasq, I meet the problem dnsmasq:failed to create listening socket :address already in use.It may be this below process prevent the dnsmasq, but i do not know how to stop this process. After i kill this process, it will restart again.
root 40012  0.0  0.0  15128   156 ?  Ss 10:16 0:00 /usr/sbin/in.tftpd --listen --user tftp --address [::]:69 --secure /var/lib/tftpboot

Comment: I have solved this problems.  tftpd-hpa is running, so that i cannot start dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service tftpd-hpa stop
stop the tftpd-hpa service and then restart dnsmasq can solve this issue